# Can I set a timer to run at 7am tomorrow?

Tags: timers

It seems to me I can either set a time for today or some relative time in the future.

But can I combine the two somehow to set a timer for 7am tomorrow, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - call `run-at-time` using the `encode-time` method to pass the time argument as mentioned in its doc string:

```
(run-at-time TIME REPEAT FUNCTION &rest ARGS)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 19.26.

Perform an action at time TIME.
Repeat the action every REPEAT seconds, if REPEAT is non-nil.
REPEAT may be an integer or floating point number.
TIME should be one of:
- a string giving today's time like "11:23pm"
  (the acceptable formats are HHMM, H:MM, HH:MM, HHam, HHAM,
  HHpm, HHPM, HH:MMam, HH:MMAM, HH:MMpm, or HH:MMPM;
  a period `.' can be used instead of a colon `:' to separate
  the hour and minute parts);
- a string giving a relative time like "90" or "2 hours 35 minutes"
  (the acceptable forms are a number of seconds without units
  or some combination of values using units in `timer-duration-words');
- nil, meaning now;
- a number of seconds from now;
- a value from `encode-time';
- or t (with non-nil REPEAT) meaning the next integral
  multiple of REPEAT.

The action is to call FUNCTION with arguments ARGS.

This function returns a timer object which you can use in
`cancel-timer'.
```

So you can say

```el
(run-at-time (encode-time '(0 0 7 13 6 2020 nil t nil)) nil #+my-func)
```

to run `my-func` once at 7am EDT (local time) on 2020-06-13.

N.B. For versions of emacs < 27 (?), `encode-time` had a different signature, so the above needs to be modified like this:

```el
(run-at-time (apply #'encode-time '(0 0 7 13 6 2020 nil t nil)) nil #+my-func)
```

Calculating tomorrow from today is not difficult (there may be better ways to do that than the one I use below which was thrown together in a hurry):

```el
(defun tomorrow ()
  ;;; the `(nthcdr 3 ...)' gets rid of the SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR values
  (let ((now-plus-1-day (nthcdr 3 (decode-time (+ (* 24 60 60) 
                                                  (time-to-seconds (current-time)))))))
    ;;; now keep three entries and get rid of the DST,TIMEZONE entries
    (setf (nthcdr 3 now-plus-1-day) nil)
    ;;; return (MONTH DAY YEAR)
    now-plus-1-day))
```

This returns a three-element list `(MONTH DAY YEAR)`.

So now you can combine the two and say

```el
(run-at-time (encode-time `(0 0 7 ,@(tomorrow) nil t nil)) nil #+my-func)
```

using the [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) mechanism to splice in the list that `tomorrow` returns.

N.B. For versions of emacs < 27 (?), `encode-time` had a different signature, so the above needs to be modified like this:

```el
(run-at-time (apply #'encode-time '(0 0 7 ,@(tomorrow) nil t nil)) nil #+my-func)
```

You should check the doc string of encode-time as well (the following is from bleeding-edge emacs 28.0.50 - as noted above, for emacs versions < 27(?), the signature of `encode-time` was different, so check the doc string locally):

```
encode-time is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(encode-time TIME &rest OBSOLESCENT-ARGUMENTS)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 19.29.
  This function does not change global state, including the match data.

Convert TIME to a timestamp.

TIME is a list (SECOND MINUTE HOUR DAY MONTH YEAR IGNORED DST ZONE).
in the style of `decode-time', so that (encode-time (decode-time ...)) works.
In this list, ZONE can be nil for Emacs local time, t for Universal
Time, `wall' for system wall clock time, or a string as in the TZ
environment variable.  It can also be a list (as from
`current-time-zone') or an integer (as from `decode-time') applied
without consideration for daylight saving time.  If ZONE specifies a
time zone with daylight-saving transitions, DST is t for daylight
saving time, nil for standard time, and -1 to cause the daylight
saving flag to be guessed.

As an obsolescent calling convention, if this function is called with
6 or more arguments, the first 6 arguments are SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR,
DAY, MONTH, and YEAR, and specify the components of a decoded time,
where DST assumed to be -1 and FORM is omitted.  If there are more
than 6 arguments the *last* argument is used as ZONE and any other
extra arguments are ignored, so that (apply #'encode-time
(decode-time ...)) works.  In this obsolescent convention, DST and
ZONE default to -1 and nil respectively.

Years before 1970 are not guaranteed to work.  On some systems,
year values as low as 1901 do work.
```

EDIT: added some backward-compatibiity notes for `encode-time`. I'm not sure when the signature changed but a comment indicates that 26.2 uses the old implementation and my experiments with 26.3 indicate the same thing. I have not tested emacs-27, hence the question marks.

Thanks to @Tom for pointing the problem out.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I missed encode-time, because I was reading the info manual, and it's only a single sentence there among lots of other info. BTW, it would be more convenient if the user could simply specify "7am 1 day" meaning 7am a day from now. Strange that it's not supported, because the elements are there.

Comment: That's a UI matter and e.g. `org-read-date` allows some things like that but not exactly what you want: maybe (probably?)  someone has written a function to translate human-friendly specs like "7am tomorrow" to the format that `run-at-time` expects. If not, maybe you can write your own implementation: if it's good enough, then everybody will adopt it! The main problem will be to detect ambiguity and inform the (human) user so that they can fix it.

Comment: I use orgmode for scheduling and its date read function is really convenient, so it could probably be adapted for use in run-at-time in some form. Orgmode is part of emacs, so it would make sense to reuse the code, instead of writing it from scratch.

Comment: But AFAIK it cannot combine times and relative dates: `7am +1d` is not understood. There may be other limitations.

Comment: If it's past 7am then `7am` in orgmode gives you 7am  tomorrow which is nice. `run-at-time` could do this by default. And if it's before 7am and you want 7am tomorrow then I usually use the day. So if it's 6am Sat then `7am Sun` sets 7am to tomorrow.

Comment: But that's exactly the point: the function has to resolve any ambiguities and come up with a unique date/time spec that is what the user expected. But not all users expect the same thing (ISTR that there are many questions on this site, questioning the choices that `org-read-date` makes). And no, `run-at-time` should stay as is, although if we can get wide agreement about the UI function, it migh be desirable to add a new `run-at-...` function that uses it.

Comment: FYI, I tried it and the encode-time calls in your example throw errors for me on emacs 26.2, because they only get one argument (apply not used): `(encode-time '(0 0 7 13 6 2020 nil t nil))`

Comment: Edited, adding some notes and a a 26.x-compatible variant of the code. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Apparently, emacs 27 changed the signature, but it also supports the old one, so the old format works for both.

Comment: Yes, but internally all calls to `encode-time` have been changed to the new format, so it's likely that the old format will go away eventually.